# Why does the turtle window stops responding?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, python-turtle

I am trying to use the turtle module for a python, but it stops responding in further compilations after the first successful compilation. I have tried this both in Spyder and Jupyter but the result is the same.

Edit 1: This is the code I used, it is not self-made I learnt it from youtube.

Edit 2: The kernel keeps dying after I close the turtle window due to it not responding

```
import turtle

wn=turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Made by ")
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.setup(width=800,height=600)
wn.tracer(0)                   #Keeps the screen up

#Paddle A
paddle_a=turtle.Turtle()       #object of turtle
paddle_a.speed(0)              #speed of animation
paddle_a.shape("square")
paddle_a.color("red")
paddle_a.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)    #default size is 20*20
paddle_a.penup()               #not to draw lines
paddle_a.goto(-350,0)

#Paddle B
paddle_b=turtle.Turtle()       #object of turtle
paddle_b.speed(0)              #speed of animation
paddle_b.shape("square")
paddle_b.color("blue")
paddle_b.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)    #default size is 20*20
paddle_b.penup()               #not to draw lines
paddle_b.goto(350,0)

#Ball
ball=turtle.Turtle()       #object of turtle
ball.speed(0)              #speed of animation
ball.shape("circle")
ball.color("white")
ball.penup()               #not to draw lines
ball.goto(0,0)
ball.dx=0.09                 #moves by 2 pixels
ball.dy=0.09

#Function
def paddle_a_up():
    y=paddle_a.ycor()       #mentions the y coordinate
    y=y+20
    paddle_a.sety(y)        #set y coordinate to new y

def paddle_a_down():
    y=paddle_a.ycor()       #mentions the y coordinate
    y=y-20
    paddle_a.sety(y)        #set y coordinate to new y

def paddle_b_up():
    y=paddle_b.ycor()       #mentions the y coordinate
    y=y+20
    paddle_b.sety(y)        #set y coordinate to new y

def paddle_b_down():
    y=paddle_b.ycor()       #mentions the y coordinate
    y=y-20
    paddle_b.sety(y)        #set y coordinate to new y
    
#Keyboard binding
wn.listen()                 #listen keyboard input
wn.onkeypress(paddle_a_up,'w')
wn.onkeypress(paddle_a_down,'s')
wn.onkeypress(paddle_b_up,"Up")
wn.onkeypress(paddle_b_down,"Down")

#Main loop
running=True
while running:
    wn.update()                #updates the screen
    #movement the ball
    ball.setx(ball.xcor()+ball.dx)
    ball.sety(ball.ycor()+ball.dy)
```

Comment: You need to show the code; it could be a lot of different problems.

Comment: Show your code, it's hard to help when there are a multitude of possible problems that could cause this.

Answer (score 1):

> This is the code I used, it is not self-made I learnt it from youtube.

It would have helped if the person who posted it on YouTube had learnt turtle properly.  The main loop of this code is potentially blocking tkinter events.  The code also does more work than necessary by not oriented the turtles to its advantage.  See if my rewrite works better for you:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

# Functions
def paddle_a_up():
    paddle_a.forward(20)

def paddle_a_down():
    paddle_a.backward(20)

def paddle_b_up():
    paddle_b.forward(20)

def paddle_b_down():
    paddle_b.backward(20)

# Main loop
def move():
    x, y = ball.position()
    ball.setposition(x + ball.dx, y + ball.dy)

    screen.update()
    screen.ontimer(move)

screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor('black')
screen.setup(width=800, height=600)
screen.tracer(False)

# Paddle A
paddle_a = Turtle()
paddle_a.shape('square')
paddle_a.shapesize(stretch_wid=1, stretch_len=5)
paddle_a.setheading(90)
paddle_a.penup()
paddle_a.color('red')
paddle_a.setx(-350)

# Paddle B
paddle_b = paddle_a.clone()
paddle_b.color('blue')
paddle_b.setx(350)

# Ball
ball = Turtle()
ball.shape('circle')
ball.color('white')
ball.penup()

ball.dx = 1  # user defined object properties
ball.dy = 1

# Keyboard binding
screen.onkeypress(paddle_a_up, 'w')
screen.onkeypress(paddle_a_down, 's')
screen.onkeypress(paddle_b_up, 'Up')
screen.onkeypress(paddle_b_down, 'Down')
screen.listen()

move()

screen.mainloop()
```

Running under Spyder and/or Jupyter adds further complications when you restart a turtle program.  The above was only tested at the command line.